# Are nouns like 'Create' appropriate in a compound?

Tags: programming, compounds

I'm solving a problem where I must choose between 'CreateMethod' and 'CreationMethod'. The first one fits me better because I want to indicate an action, not the process invoked by that action.
I'm sorry if CamelCasing offends anyone, its how we software developers make our words.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence containing CM that you would use? If not, this really isn't the place to ask this question, as it wouldn't fall within the site parameters (normal English).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth
"Type 'Int32' is not supported by the current create method."

Comment: Essentially, **you**'re introducing a new collocation (and these things tend to become quickly fixed as compounds or idioms), so 'create method' is as acceptable as 'creation method'. I agree, 'create method' better connotes the action rather than the process.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I just thought that people might find 'create method' confusing because if you derive it from a sentence, it appears to be an instruction instead of a name.

Comment: The context and phrasing usually makes the intent clear.

Comment: In particular, since you have _the_ before _create_, it can't be interpreted as a verb.

Comment: There are also precedents for V + N compound nouns: to-do list; stop button; go-kart; throw cover ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming of variables, which is specifically off-topic.

Comment: @BrianHooper - No. I didn't ask how to name variables, I explicitly asked how to create a correct compound. The fact that the compound serves as a variable is context, not content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question belongs to a programming forum. It pertains to the naming conventions of verbs and nouns coded in software.

Look at this recommendation from Oracle for the Java programming language:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

It says the name of a method should be a verb.

A method or a function is an active act of performing a task. It is a well-known unquestioned etiquette to ease collaboration, which you should avoid violating. For example

- doSomething()
- kill(processId)
- getProcessCount()
- setThreadName(name)

It should be different for naming of objects or variables, which should be nouns, gerunds or participles

- temperatureSetting
- creationMethod
- methodCreationTime
- latencyInMillisecs

For enumerated or categorical choices (Enum) it should depend on what the categorization is for. If it is decided that the Enum is a categorization of actions, then all the members of the category should be verbs. Conversely, if it is decided that it is a categorization of nouns/participles, then all members of the category should e nouns/participles

e.g., if the Enum is for choice of commands to be sent to a machine

```
enum CentrifugalPurifierCommand{
  STALL,
  WAIT,
  SERVE,
  ACCELERATE,
  DECELERATE,
  RECALIBRATE
}
```

For an Enum documenting the state of a machine

```
enum CentrifugalPurifierState{
  STALLED,
  WAITING,
  ACCELERATING,
  ACCELERATED,
  DECELERATING,
  RECALIBRATING
}
```

"*I want to indicate an action, not the process invoked by that action*"

Conventions require you not to do that. You should avoid confusing your collaborators by concocting your own conventions.

If you need to set or find the method, then your method should say either of

- setCreationMethod(methodName)
- getCreationMethod()

If you are using a delegate, and since a delegate is effectively a reference to a method and invoked like a method, you should name a delegate as a verb.

```
Delegate int EatPieDelegate(PieType pieType);
int eat(PieType pieType) { ....}
int gobble(PieType pieType) { ....}
int chew(PieType pieType) { ....}

EatPieDelegate startEating = new EatPieDelegate(eat);
int piesEaten = startEating (applePie);
```

The gist of my message is **STICK TO PROGRAMMING CONVENTIONS** to make life easier for other people.